# Apache mod-rewrite rule to change subdomain.domain.tld to domain.tld/subdomain

Tags: apache-2.2, domain, subdomain, rewrite

What would the rewrite rule be to change `subdomain.domain.tld` to `domain.tld/subdomain`?

Or should I look at a VirtualServer directive to take `subdomain.domain.tld` and serve it from a DocRoot that happens to be also found at `domain.tld/subdomain`?

And where would the rewrite rule want to live, if using a rewrite is more appropriate?

#### update - found the link here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don't need to setup a virtual server, just use this rule :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.tld$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://domain.tld/%1/$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: quick follow-up.. where does the rewrite rule go?

Comment: found it - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: @nahar - thanks for the rewrite rule, this is precisely what I wanted!