# redirect not-active subdomains

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

**EDIT:**

How can you redirect all non-active subdomains to 'www'?

Here I try to redirect all subdomains not listed to 'www'.. I can't make it work properly because %1 and %2 doesn't return anything.. Here I'm trying to redirect to google.com just to check the returned %2 value.., but it doesn't return anything and the redirect url is `http://www.google.com/`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        !^(admin|demo|www)\.([^\.]+\.[^\.]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$          http://www.google.com/%2 [L,R=301]
```

this is what I really want to do

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        !^(admin|demo|www)\.([^\.]+\.[^\.]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$          http://www.%2/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: give actual examples of start end points and I can write one

Comment: like this? ....

Comment: could anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|admin|files|mysql\.)domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

Untested but it should work..

Comment: shouldn't the \. in the rewritecond be outside the parens?

Comment: what does the NE flag mean?

Comment: I have edited my q

Comment: NE is no escape do you don't double encode the url

Answer (score -1):

Presuming DNS entries already exist, you *could* use [something I do](https://serverfault.com/questions/166505/apache-mod-rewrite-rule-to-change-subdomain-domain-tld-to-domain-tld-subdomain) on a couple domains:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.mydomain\.com$
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/%1/$1 [L,R]
```

This takes requests in the form of `sub.domain.com` and pushes it to `domain.com/sub`.

You could remove the `%1` and get the following which would *not* use the subdomain-to-path method I'm employing thusly:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.mydomain\.com$
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: thats not what im looking for