# dynamic rewrites using $1, %1, %2 etc

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

how to make more complex and dynamic rewrites using $1, %1, %2 etc.

I'm trying to make a more dynamic rewrite (got a lot of domians pointing to the same server/site)

```
#   put 'www' as subdomain if none is given
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        ^([^\.]+\.[^\.]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$          http://www.%1/$1 [L,R=301]

#   rewrite subdomains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        ^(admin|files|imap|mysql)\.[^\.]+\.[^\.]+$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}      !^/_(admin|files|imap|mysql)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$          /_%1/$1 [L]

#   redirect to subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        ^www\.([^\.]+\.[^\.]+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}      ^/_([^/]*)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$          http://%1.domain.com/ [L,R=301]

#   rewrite 'secure' subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        ^(demo|secure)\.[^\.]+\.[^\.]+$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}      !^/_secure/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$          /_secure/$1 [L]
```

but now I'm confronting a problem..

by `#redirect to subdomain` I can't figure out how to solve the condition and rule like the other I have made.. somehow I need to extract the domain from the first condition and then use it in the rule with %1, but how can you do that when you got another condition in between?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The capture data for `%1` etc is used from the `RewriteCond` immediately above the `RewriteRule`.

Is there any reason your URI path evaluation/capture can't just occur in the `RewriteRule`?  Something like this (I think this is what you're going for?):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        ^www\.([^\.]+\.[^\.]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/_([^/]*)/$        http://$1.%1/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: now it doesn't redirect..

Comment: if I change the rewrite rule with this to test it it doesn't work.. RewriteRule ^/_  http://www.google.com [L,R=301]

Comment: got it :) RewriteRule ^_([^/]+)/  http://$1.%1/ [L,R=301]

Comment: @clarkk That's the context sensitivity of `RewriteRule` at work - My config assumed they were just in a `VirtualHost` block, where absolute paths are used, but when they're in a `Directory` block or .htaccess file, the relative path is used.

Comment: maybe you could help me out here too http://serverfault.com/questions/273632/redirect-not-active-subdomains